# How to initiate spirals in this model?

Tags: matlab, finite-difference, simulation, computational-biology

I am trying to reproduce [Tang & Othmer](http://www.math.umn.edu/~othmer/papers/Tang:1995:EOW.pdf) paper which is related to excitations and oscillations in G-protein model in *Dictyostelium discoideum*, an amoeba species. The mathematical model in the paper is like below:

[image]

where $w_1,w_2,w_3,w_4,w_5,u_1,u_2,u_4$ are biochemicals and other parameters are constants associated with *Dictyostelium discoideum*, $sr(.)$ is secretion rate function. 
I am supposed to simulate a situation in a square mesh where cells are uniformly distributed and interact each other. $w_5$ is the extracellular cAMP (cyclic AMP) which diffuses out from the amoeba cells and creates spiral wave forms in space under some conditions. So I basically simulated this using Euler method in MATLAB. But I am unable to generate spirals in simulation.

**Can someone give me some idea to generate $w_5$ spirals in the mesh?**

Below is the results (for 5 minutes) considering a single cell and no diffusion content. (Just to show that I have reproduced some results from paper)
[image]

One 2D solution looks like below (from the paper) :

[image]

And my attempt to this problem is unsuccessful. What I did to initiate output is first define every cells with an initial value set for variables like $w_1, w_2 ...$ etc except a patch where those values are $180°$ shifted (`imagesc` plot of $w_5$ shown in the figure) . I selected these initial values from the ODE plots. But this arrangement is proving to be unsuccessful.

[image]

---

**UPDATE** : Now I improved my code so that output is bounded between 2 values. Its not blowing up any more. I can provide my code if necessary. Here is the [link](https://youtu.be/JIS9Y5s6scQ) to a video output I created.

Comment: I'm confused, how come the question shows a one-time-zero-space-dimensional plot, but the rest is about a 2+1 pde? Also, um, have you tried doing the same thing they did in that paper with the same parameter values? If you have, just put the incorrect results directly in the question. Without details these kinds of debugging questions turn into a kind of guessing game (IME), which isn't much fun, and is also usually considered off-topic. Bandwidth and question space are cheap anyway.

Comment: @Kirill : The second figure is the realization of a single cell dynamics with no diffusion term.

Comment: I'm more confused now. Are you asking how to solve a differential equation with diffusion in it? Or is it that you have implemented it, but it's not working correctly? What exactly does "unable" mean here? You can't get anything useful in 2d after neglecting the sole diffusion term.

Comment: @Kirill : Or is it that you have implemented it, but it's not working correctly? - Yes I have implemented it,but not successful. See I have shown the ODE plots so as to prove that I have done that part it correctly. For 2D I do consider diffusion.

Comment: Yes, but what do the 2D solution look like? How is it unsuccessful? I.e., did you get no result at all, or did you simply fail to achieve the spirals you expect to see?

Comment: OK I will update the question.

Comment: Wait, that's a figure from the paper, not your program. I don't think that's what Bill Barth was asking.

Comment: @BillBarth , I have updated my answer.

Comment: Check the sign of your diffusion term.

Comment: @BillBarth : I have done as in paper. I have updated the question.

Comment: Does it help to set random-like initial conditions with lots of asymmetry and high frequency modes?

Comment: @Kirill I have tried with random initial conditions. But no spirals are observed. By "high frequency" do you mean changing the parameter for that too randomly among cells?

Comment: You'll definitely want to use a higher-order time discretization (not Euler).

Comment: @DavidKetcheson : Can you give me an example technique?

Comment: If you're using MATLAB, then I would try `ode45` first.

Comment: @DavidKetcheson : How can I use `ode45` along with diffusion term?

Comment: It's nothing tricky.  Google ode45 and diffusion if you need examples.

Comment: @DavidKetcheson : I just created a spiral using euler method. Thanks, but I would like to get your method. I searched internet. Can I get some sample code for `ode45` + diffusion.

Comment: Can you share a little bit about how you used ode45 to solve this? Maybe a fraction of your code? I am working on a similar problem but I don't know how to use ode45 with 2D diffusion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I managed to create a spiral finally. The method I used to initiate spiral is by initializing the mesh with a set of initial values expect a small square patch which is initialized with $180°$ phase shift with others and some having $90°$ phase shift. The link to spiral video I created is [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Jj20OUnY_m4).